# List SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml, release

Is there a plugin or any other way to list SNAPSHOT dependencies for a project?
I just need the names of such dependencies and their versions (e.g org.my.company:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: You might want to apply the [Require Release Dependencies rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html)

Answer (score 7):

`mvn dependency:list | grep -i snapshot`

or

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:::*-SNAPSHOT`

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: yes, but what if the dependency is not yet released? dependency:list gives "Could not resolve" error.

Comment: You can clean install, then you'll have it in your local repository.

Comment: I googled and this was the first return.  I get tired of peoples condescending tone toward others when answering questions (here or forums).  I also get tired of searching for answers only to have the top returns on a web search to have "use the search function" or "just google it" as the answer.  Years of condescending answers are now the top answers in searchings, well done Internet.

Comment: I submitted an edit removing the "just google it", so we can all be at peace :)

Comment: Thank you for it :)